# How to interact with Discord Bot using Axios?

Tags: node.js, axios, discord

I have a private server on Discord, with my User and a Bot which as a simple commande `/test`.

I'm using NodeJs and I would like to use this command through my user using an Axios request. I have no issue to send a message with Axios using my user, but interact with the bot is not working :

```
const data = JSON.stringify({
            "content": "hello"
        });

        const config = {
            method: 'post',
            // headers: {}
            url: 'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/AAAAAAAAAAA/messages',
            data: data
        };

        axios(config)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

This is working, my user send a message "hello".

Now I do the same but for the "interaction" (https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/receiving-and-responding). I try the command manually on my channel, get the network ressource from the browser and sent the same into PostMan.

This is the payload I use for this request `POST https://discord.com/api/v9/interactions`:

```
{
   "type":2,
   "application_id":"myBotId",
   "channel_id":"AAAAAAA", //same channel as the first request to send a text message
   "data":{}
}
```

I got the following error :
`404 Not Found (error code: 10003): Unknown Channel`, but it's the same that I used for the first request.

Can anyone help me ? Or is there another solution ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your link https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/AAAAAAAAAAA/messages and I got:

```
{"message": "401: Unauthorized", "code": 0}
```

Similar for the other...
Could it be possible that your app needs to complete some login step to work?

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAA is the id of my channel, I just don't show it here. And the token is in the headers which I don't show too